# About "will" and "promise"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Is saying that you **will** do something equivalent to saying that you **promise** to do something, such that not doing strictly what you said (e.g. late for 15 minutes with reasons) would be something as severe as breaking a promise?

Comment: There's even quite a difference between _I'll be there tomorrow_ and _I will be there tomorrow_.

Comment: This will differ among speakers, but I would say *no*. In my eyes I've only made a promise when I've promised or sworn to do something.

Answer (score 2):

*Will* and *promise* can be synonymous, but they do carry different levels of commitment depending on context.
For example if you are asked, "Can you wash the dishes?"
If you reply, "I *will* get to them before I go to bed," you are expressing intent. If you were to say, "I *promise* I will wash the dishes before bed," you are making a much stronger statement.
It is common to use *will* for commitments. It does carry a less committal tone. But, that does not prohibit others from treating it as a *promise*. 
As regards it being treated as severely, much of that has to do with context and the person to whom the commitment was made.
Example: "I will be at the job interview at 1:00pm." vs. "I will meet you for coffee at 1:00pm."

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the *will/shall* distinction, which is different in British English and American English, at least in the formal varieties.

In received British English, and in hyperformal American English until the 1970s or so, *shall* is the auxiliary verb used to form the future tense for the first person singular and plural ("I shall" and "we shall") and *will* is the auxiliary for the second and third persons ("you shall," "it shall," etc.). In that usage "I will" means something on the order of "I emphatically intend to do it" and might be understood as something in the nature of a promise, depending on how it is said.

In American English, "I will ..." is simply an indicator of future tense and should be understood as a prediction of what is likely to happen, equivalent to the British "I shall ...." There is no suggestion of emphasis, although there may be contexts in which the statement could be interpreted as a promise.